# Delete filetype only if the path includes a specific string

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm scratching my head trying to figure this one out.

We have a certain filetype that exists on disk (*.sc) that I'd like to remove but ONLY if the preceding folder path has the name "cache" in it.

```
 /jobs/job1/files/myfile.sc - Will NOT be deleted
 /jobs/job1/cache/myfile.sc - Will be deleted
```

To further complicate matters cache can appear anywhere in the folder path, it's not at a consistent depth.

```
 /jobs/job1/my_folder/subfolder/myfile.sc - Will NOT be deleted
 /jobs/job1/my_folder/cache/subfolder/myfile.sc - WILL be deleted
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `find` will solve your problem. First let's do a non-destructive test:

```sh
    find "/jobs/job1" -type f -name '*.sc' -regex '.*/cache/.*' -print
```

This will find all files:

1. in the subfolder `/jobs/job1`
2. is of a regular file type (i.e. not a directory)
3. the file name has a `.sc` suffix
4. the file path contains the word `cache`

If you are satisfied with the result, then, you can replace `-print` with `-delete`

```sh
    find "/jobs/job1" -type f -name '*.sc' -regex '.*/cache/.*' -delete
```

Comment: Hmmm, this regex finds anything under a cache folder and prints it. How would I further edit it so it ONLY finds files ending in *.sc ?

Comment: Okay, i added `-iname '*.sc'` which finds all files matching the `*.sc` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf %s\\n /**/cache/**/*.sc
```

If you are happy with the results, replace the `printf %s\\n` by `rm`.